# In-call status bar not working with landscape views

Tags: ios-simulator, call, landscape

My application runs exclusively in landscape interface orientation.  Testing on the iPhone Simulator, showed that the in-call status bar isn't working properly; only the top half of the status bar appears and clicking it does nothing.  When I changed the application to run in portrait mode, the in-call status bar started working as expected.

I also tested this using the "HelloWorld" iPhone sample app.  When run in portrait mode (i.e. sample unaltered), in-call status works fine.  When I change the sample to run in landscape mode (i.e. implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to "return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)"), it exhibits the same broken behavior seen in the landscape version of my application.

Has anyone else seen this behavior before?

Unfortunately I don't have a real iPhone to test this on.  Can anyone verify that this bug only exist in the simulator, or does it also manifest on an actual iPhone?

Thanks lots.

Answer (score 0):

A far as I know this is the correct behaviour. As the height of the screen in landscape is very small as it is it would make no sense to increase the status bar's height.